# Access to GetSlice method in F#

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm implementing slice expressions for a matrix class in F#, which means that I have to implement three `GetSlice` methods. My question is about obtaining an efficient way of doing this by leveraging existing functionality from the core library. The signatures for the three methods are as follows:

```
member GetSlice : idx1:int * start2:int option * end2:int option -> IMatrix
member GetSlice : start1:int option * end1:int option * idx2:int -> IMatrix
member GetSlice : start1:int option * end1:int option * 
                  start2:int option * end2:int option -> IMatrix
```

Consider the final of these three. The matrix class has a private `float[,]` field called `entries` which holds the matrix data. The most natural implementation would be something like this:

```
member this.GetSlice (?start1 : int, ?end1 : int, ?start2 : int, ?end2 : int) =
    let newEntries = entries.GetSlice(?start1 = start1, ?end1 = end1,
                                      ?start2 = start2, ?end2 = end2)
    new Matrix(newEntries),
```

which simply uses the `GetSlice` functionality of the `float[,]` implementation. However, this does not compile, as the `GetSlice` extension method is not available (at least not with the namespaces I've opened). I would have thought that this method was available by default in FSharp.Core, but this doesn't really seem to be the case. A manual implementation based on slice expressions for `float[,]` could look something like this

```
member this.GetSlice (?start1 : int, ?end1 : int, ?start2 : int, ?end2 : int) =
    let newEntries = match (start1, end1, start2, end2) with
        | Some(sta1), Some(end1), Some(sta2), Some(end2) -> entries.[sta1 .. end1, sta2 .. end2]
        | Some(sta1), Some(end1), Some(sta2), None -> entries.[sta1 .. end1, sta2 .. ]
        (...)
    new Matrix(entries),
```

which would necessitate 16 pattern cases and is thus somewhat inconvenient. Is there an easier option, perhaps based on somehow gaining access to the `GetSlice` extension method of `float[,]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `defaultArg` to assign a values for those option and just slice with them on your array :

```
member __.GetSlice (?start1 : int, ?end1 : int, ?start2 : int, ?end2 : int) =
  let start1, end1, start2, end2 =
    defaultArg start1 0,
    defaultArg end1 (Array2D.length1 entries - 1),
    defaultArg start2 0,
    defaultArg end2 (Array2D.length2 entries - 1)

  new Matrix (entries.[start1 .. end1, start2 .. end2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are just syntactic sugar that make a static method look like an instance method.

If you hit "Go to definition" on the `GetSlice` extension method (I'm guessing you saw it working in another project?), you will be able to see the 'real' static method behind it. It will be something like:

```
public static class SomeMatrixUtilityLibrary.ExtensionMethods
{
    public static float[,] GetSlice(this float[,] array2d,
                                    int start1, 
                                    int end1,
                                    int start2,
                                    int end2)
   {
        //... 
   }
}
```

*That* static method will work just fine in F#, you'll only need to invoke it normally instead of through the extension syntax.

Comment: Well, I actually don't know in which module to find the GetSlice extension for float[,], and I can't see it through "Go to definition" because it's not even detected by VS2015. I only know that it exists because it allows me to use the slice expressions in F#.